# R: interaction in model output

Tags: r, model, interpretation, interaction, lme4-nlme

Let's say you're trying to fit a model to a dataset that includes categorical variables, group (A or B) and treatment (1, 2, 3 or 4).

In R, your model formula would be **DV ~ group * treatment** (DV stands for dependent variable) and your model output will look like this:

```
(intercept)                 [...]
groupB                      [...]
treatment2                  [...]
treatment3                  [...]
treatment4                  [...]
groupB:treatment2           [...]
groupB:treatment3           [...]
groupB:treatment4           [...]
```

My question is how to interpret this kind of output. Below is what I believe is right for the interpretation of the main effects, and what puzzles me about the interaction parameters.

```
(intercept)
```

This the reference value, i.e. for treatment 1 in group A.

```
groupB
```

This is the difference between group A and group B for treatment 1 only.

```
treatment2
```

This is the difference between treatment 1 and treatment 2, within group A only. It indeed still refers to the intercept value.
Same logic for the two following estimates ("treatment3" and "treatment4").

```
groupB:treatment2
```

Here is where I get puzzled. Is this testing if **the difference between treatment1 and treatment2 is the same in groupB compared to groupA**, or is it testing if if **the difference between groupA and groupB is the same for treatment1 compared to treatment2**.

I thought this question would be very basic, but I went through several R books with no luck and found inconsistent answers on here (see [How to interpret 2-way and 3-way interaction in lmer?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/87412/how-to-interpret-2-way-and-3-way-interaction-in-lmer) for support for the first idea and [Interpreting the regression output from a mixed model when interactions between categorical variables are included](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/33709/interpreting-the-regression-output-from-a-mixed-model-when-interactions-between) for the other way).

If that matters, I'm working with the glmer function of the lme4 package.

Thanks!

Comment: Both actually. These cases can't be distinguished.

Comment: Have a look at the effects package

Comment: If visual inspection is helpful for you, you might want to check the `sjp.int` function of the [sjPlot-package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sjPlot/index.html) ([see examples here](http://strengejacke.de/sjPlot/sjp.int/)). Maybe [this blog-posting](http://www.theanalysisfactor.com/clarifications-on-interpreting-interactions-in-regression/) is also helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It think Roland in your comment is right. I guess it could be expanded as an answer. If you draw a table summing your coefficients for each case, you end up with something like that :

```
+------+--------+--------+
|      | treat1 | treat2 |
+------+--------+--------+
| gpb  |   a    |    b   |
| gpa  |   c    |    d   |
+------+--------+--------+
```

Treatement 3 is volontary omitted. You have :

- $a=intercept+groupB$
- $b=intercept+groupB+treatment2+groupB:treatment2$
- $c=intercept$
- $d=intercept+treatment2$

Your first proposition could be translated as studying $(b-a)-(d-c)$.
Detail : The difference between treatment1 and treatment2 in groupB $(b-a)$, compared to the difference between treatment1 and treatment2 in groupA $(d-c)$.

Similarly, your second proposition could be translated as studying $(b-d)-(a-c)$.

It's then the same expression, and it indeed equals $groupB:treatment2$